# remove comments without affecting values in the config file

Tags: perl, awk

I have a config file and I need to remove the comments starting with # to the end of the line.
But it should not affect the values that are in double/single quotes.

My input file:

```
# comment1
# comment2
#hbase_table_name=mytable # hbase table.
hbase_table_name=newtable # hbase table.
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust#100"  # Name of the application
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
```

The perl command that I'm trying

```
perl -0777 -pe ' s/^\s*$//gms ; s/#.*?$//gm; s/^\s*$//gms;s/^$//gm' config.txt
```

The output I'm getting is

```
hbase_table_name=newtable
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust
app_user= 'all
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
```

But the required output is

```
hbase_table_name=newtable
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust#100"
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
```

I'm looking for a bash solution using any tools - awk or perl that can solve this.

A rare scenario may be with config entry like

```
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users - "all" of them
```

and the result should be `app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

while (<DATA>){
    if (m/^\h*#/) {next;};
    if (m/((['"])[^\2]*\2)/) {print substr $_, 0, @+[0]; print "\n"; next; }
    s/#.*$//; print ;
}

__DATA__
# comment1
# comment2
#hbase_table_name=mytable # hbase table.
hbase_table_name=newtable # hbase table.
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust#100"  # Name of the application
#app_name= "cust#100"  # Name of the application
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
# from comments, other lines
hbase_table_name=newtable ## hbase table.
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users - "all" of them
```

Output:

```
hbase_table_name=newtable 
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust#100"
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
hbase_table_name=newtable 
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'
```

Change `<DATA>` to `<>` and to use on a file...

Comment: yes it works great.. what is the difference between \h and \s..

Comment: @stack0114106: *what is the difference between \h and \s* In most regex flavors, `\s` includes line terminators so `/ABC\s+DEF/` matches `ABC DEF` and matches `ABC\nDEF`. It is the equivalent of the POSIX `[[:space:]]` character class and includes `[ \t\v\r\n\f]`. The regex `/ABC\h+DEF/` matches only a horizontal space (no line feed are matched, only `[ \t]` which is equivalent to the POSIX `[[:blank:]]` character class). If it is available, use it for a match you only intend for a single line.

Comment: In this case, somewhat academic since we are reading the file line-by-line. If you gulp the file with `0777` it is NOT academic!

Comment: Many thanks for the \h reference, not sure how I missed that all these years.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following(written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk '
/^#/{
  next
}
/".*"|\047.*\047/{
  match($0,/.*#/)
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
  next
}
{
  sub(/#.*/,"")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
/^#/{                                   ##Checking condition if a line starts from #  then do following.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/".*"|\047.*\047/{                      ##Checking condition if a line matching regex from " to * OR single quote to single quote in current line.
  match($0,/.*#/)                       ##If above TRUE then come inside block; using match to match everything till # here.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)     ##Printing substring which prints from starting to length of matched regex with -1 to remove # in it.
  next                                  ##next willskip all further statements from here.
}
{
  sub(/#.*/,"")                         ##This statement will executewhen either a line is NOT starting from # OR  does not have single/double quote in it.
}
1                                       ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
```